# Short story about a guy in a half-broken down spaceship and a fleet from Earth fleeing from some enemy, and an engineer from a planet of engineers

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

It was about a guy in a half-broken down spaceship and a fleet from Earth fleeing from some enemy who meets a engineer who has never flown before from a planet of engineers.

It's a short story that I read in English and I think it was in a book of short stories.

It is similar to Cogswell's "The Spectre general" but it's a different story.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Is there anything further you can tell us to help us narrow it down? Was this a movie? TV series? Novel? When did you watch/read it, and in what language? Anything at all you can remember will be of use.

Comment: It was a short story that i read it was in English and i think it was in a book of short stories

Comment: It sounds a bit like Cogswell's "The Spectre general".

Comment: The story I remember runs along similar line but is not cogswell’s story

Comment: Can you think of some ways in which they differ?

Comment: It was not as long as that may be ten pages long so it may have been an abridged version   i was reading  a lot of short story books at the time   there was no political elements to the story i remember.